# Hiding android SoftKey board

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

How to hide the SoftKeyboard from screen when edittext is accepting input from remote?
I have tried

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

It hides the softkeyboard but it also stops the edittext from  taking input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: @AndrewSchuster yes I have tried it, but it stops edittext input

Comment: Did you only try the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
public static final void hideSoftKeyBoard(Context context, EditText editText) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Thanks